# SSIS Package Adding DataFlow components Programmatically

Tags: ssis

Can we add new Data Transformation Components programatically to an existing SSIS Package.
The newly added component should be in between two exixting Data Transformation components. Is this possible?

Comment: why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: i have a situation.. i have a datasource and its output is fed to a script component. If we add extra columns to the source it doesn't get added as an input to script component until i add them maually. I cannot edit the package each time a new column is added. So i thought whether there is a way to access it programatically.. Can you please suggest me somthing on this

Answer (score 0):

You can't add it in the running package - packages can't modify themselves. But you can modify the package through the SSIS API immediately prior to running it. You can do this with a driver application or even via a script task in a

Comment: Can you please throw some light on how to do this in a script task?